# How to run Vagrant provisioning on the first run?

Tags: command-line, vagrant, virtual-machine

I have a very simple Vagrant file like this:

```
  config.vm.box = "precise32"
  config.vm.synced_folder "./src", "/vagrant/src/"
  config.vm.network "forwarded_port", guest: 8080, host: 8080
  config.vm.provision :shell, :path => "install.sh"
```

When I do `vagrant up` the `install.sh` is not called, but I have to reload with `--provision`. How do I run `install.sh` on the first up?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

From Vagrant 1.3 onwards, provisioning runs automatically only at the very first boot, when the machine gets created.

If you need to run it on the subsequent `reload` or `up`, you have to call it explicitly:

```
vagrant up --provision
```

See also: [GH-1776](https://github.com/mitchellh/vagrant/issues/1776) [[commit]](https://github.com/mitchellh/vagrant/commit/e2ddab532d575d786365c3870964a60692bdf1d7).

Comment: https://github.com/mitchellh/vagrant/issues/2310 issue to update doc and provide an second script