# When does Vagrant run provisioners?

Tags: vagrant

I have a very simple `Vagrantfile`. Basically, it's the default file with a lot of stuff removed and a super-easy inline-shell provisioner:

```
Vagrant.configure("2") do |config|
  config.vm.define "test" do |test|
    test.vm.box = "precise64"
    test.vm.box_url = "http://files.vagrantup.com/precise64.box"

    test.vm.network :forwarded_port, guest: 3000, host: 3000

    test.vm.network :private_network, ip: "192.168.33.100"

    test.vm.provider :virtualbox do |vb|
      vb.customize [ "modifyvm", :id, "--cpus", 2 ]
      vb.customize [ "modifyvm", :id, "--memory", 1024 ]
    end

    test.vm.provision :shell, :inline => "echo \"Hello world!\""
  end
end
```

When I run `vagrant up` for the first time, the machine gets created, is booted and the shell provisioner is run as expected: The last line on the console says `Hello world!`.

Now, if I run `vagrant halt` and `vagrant up` a second time, the machine boots, but does not run the provisioner. At least no message is printed out to the terminal.

In my opinion this is in contrast to the [Vagrant documentation](http://docs.vagrantup.com/v2/provisioning/basic_usage.html) which states that:

> Provisioners are run in three cases: `vagrant up`, `vagrant reload`, and `vagrant provision`.

Why is the script not run?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[How to run Vagrant provisioning on the first run?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19358901/vagrant-up-and-provision) answers my question. Apparently this was a change in Vagrant a while ago…

Comment: traceback: https://github.com/mitchellh/vagrant/issues/2310 issue to update doc and provide an second script

Answer (score 3):

I am not sure if this has changed, but in regards to shell scripts, you can also use the `run: "always"` flag to ensure that the shell script gets executed [at all times](http://docs.vagrantup.com/v2/provisioning/basic_usage.html).

```
Vagrant.configure("2") do |config|
  config.vm.provision "shell", inline: "echo hello",
    run: "always"
end
```