# How do you reset Vagrant 1.6.3 provisioned status?

Tags: vagrant, provisioning

**Background:**
My team distributes boxes that are provisioned via vagrant. The boxes are quite often used as baseboxes upon which additional provisioning is desired. Vagrant version is 1.6.3 on MacOSX 10.9.3.

**Problem:** 
vagrant detects that the box was always provisioned and by default skips the provisioning phase unless otherwise forced via --provision or vagrant provision. I would like the team using the previously provisioned boxes to interact with distributed boxes without the need to use provision flags.

**Question:**
How do I detect and reset the provisioned status of the box so it reruns provisioners by default?

**Example:**

Sample Vagrantfile:

```rb
Vagrant.configure("2") do |config|
  config.vm.box = "chef/centos-6.5"
  config.vm.provision "shell", inline: "echo Hello, World"
end
```

Initial vagrant up:

```
$ vagrant up
Bringing machine 'default' up with 'virtualbox' provider...
==> default: Importing base box 'chef/centos-6.5'...
==> default: Matching MAC address for NAT networking...
==> default: Setting the name of the VM: example-delme_default_1409678677244_49440
==> default: Fixed port collision for 22 => 2222. Now on port 2202.
==> default: Clearing any previously set network interfaces...
==> default: Preparing network interfaces based on configuration...
    default: Adapter 1: nat
==> default: Forwarding ports...
    default: 22 => 2202 (adapter 1)
==> default: Booting VM...
==> default: Waiting for machine to boot. This may take a few minutes...
    default: SSH address: 127.0.0.1:2202
    default: SSH username: vagrant
    default: SSH auth method: private key
==> default: Machine booted and ready!
==> default: Checking for guest additions in VM...
==> default: Mounting shared folders...
    default: /vagrant => /Users/user/temp/example-delme
==> default: Running provisioner: shell...
    default: Running: inline script
==> default: Hello, World
```

Second vagrant up:

```
$ vagrant halt -f && vagrant up
==> default: Forcing shutdown of VM...
Bringing machine 'default' up with 'virtualbox' provider...
==> default: Clearing any previously set forwarded ports...
==> default: Fixed port collision for 22 => 2222. Now on port 2202.
==> default: Clearing any previously set network interfaces...
==> default: Preparing network interfaces based on configuration...
    default: Adapter 1: nat
==> default: Forwarding ports...
    default: 22 => 2202 (adapter 1)
==> default: Booting VM...
==> default: Waiting for machine to boot. This may take a few minutes...
    default: SSH address: 127.0.0.1:2202
    default: SSH username: vagrant
    default: SSH auth method: private key
==> default: Machine booted and ready!
==> default: Checking for guest additions in VM...
==> default: Mounting shared folders...
    default: /vagrant => /Users/user/temp/example-delme
==> default: Machine already provisioned. Run `vagrant provision` or use the `--provision`
==> default: to force provisioning. Provisioners marked to run always will still run.
```

The problem is shown in the console output, "Machine already provisioned".

Comment: there's nothing wrong with your example, provision runs on first up only by default. 
how your entire workflow look like? is it something like: you start from basebox, provision it, pack it into box, copy box over to other person, add box to vagrant, vagrant up?

Comment: Looks like you will need to use the --provision flag or `vagrant provision` as indicated in the error message. Check out: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19358901/vagrant-up-and-provision

Comment: @nikhil specifying the provision options is what I want to avoid

Comment: @MichaelS the workflow is as you specify. I've been thinking that perhaps I should use packer instead to "fork" a basebox.

Comment: I did find a hack in by deleting `.vagrant\machines\minimal\virtualbox\action_provision` and that causes an implicit provision next time I `up` or `reload`.